# Typescript: Define an interface/type where at least one of two properties is present (both could be present as well)

Tags: typescript

I want to describe the following interface

```
interface IDamageDetailsBase {
    id: string;
    referenceId: string;
    imageId: string;
}
```

The catch is that in the above object the following combinations are possible

- id & referenceId, both can be present
- Only id can be present
- If id is not present, referenceId will be present
- It's not possible that both id and referenceId are absent

I tried the following

```
interface IDamageDetailsBase {
  imageId: string;
}

type IDamageDetails = (
  | { id: string }
  | { referenceId: string }
  | { referenceId: string; id: string }) &
  IDamageDetailsBase;

const getId = (damageDetail: IDamageDetails) => damageDetail.id || damageDetail.referenceId
```

This gives me the following errors

```
Property 'id' does not exist on type 'IDamageDetails'.
  Property 'id' does not exist on type '{ referenceId: string; } & IDamageDetailsBase'.
Property 'referenceId' does not exist on type 'IDamageDetails'.
  Property 'referenceId' does not exist on type '{ id: string; } & IDamageDetailsBase'.
```

Could someone please explain to me how I can model this?

Comment: My IntelliJ install managed to break so I can't verify this but would something like this work:
type IDamageDetails = (
  | { id: string ; referenceId?: string }
  | { id?: string ;referenceId: string }
  | { referenceId: string; id: string }) &
  IDamageDetailsBase;

Comment: Added a simpler alternative, so you don't need to change types at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Without changing the types, you can also just use the [in type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator):

```
// getId: (damageDetail: IDamageDetails) => string
const getId = (damageDetail: IDamageDetails) =>
    "id" in damageDetail ? damageDetail.id : damageDetail.referenceId
```

[Sample Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=13&ssc=70&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE4Fs4HMLoRhzAA2AzgEJzkoDeAsAFDKvLA76oAmAXMuTBRQuANzMAvs2ZgAngAcUGbHgJESFZAF5kACmZtkAH2R12fAUJHIpLNibNQIMaBBBIe-QcJC4bB%201NkJxcndwhPSx8xcy8rXxsASmQAMgDWZU41YjIqGghxJmYAemLkfDBI3W4VfEIc0n5M1XqNcmStAD4okWYEAHsQQXKiHm09GqzWsibMKfVcjs705AAiYG5V9hBkSZaF0mQAfl3a7I0AOg3kfj26g4uQ13CeIA)

---

**Original answer:**

You get the error, because only common properties in a union type can be accessed without having narrowed the type further down before.

`referenceId` does not exist in the first union part and the second union constituent does not contain `id`. So first step is to add missing common props with  `undefined` type:

```
type IDamageDetails = (
    | { id: string; referenceId: undefined }
    | { id: undefined; referenceId: string }
    | { id: string; referenceId: string }) &
    IDamageDetailsBase;
```

With help of [nullish coalescing operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing) you now will always get a `string` back:

```
// getId: (damageDetail: IDamageDetails) => string
const getId = (damageDetail: IDamageDetails) => damageDetail.id ?? damageDetail.referenceId
```

That works, because `IDamageDetails` is a [discriminated union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) with `id: undefined` and `referenceId: undefined` being [discriminant properties](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-2.html#non-unit-types-as-union-discriminants). They contain a singleton `undefined` type, which exists in exactly one of the three union cases. So the compiler will know, that given one is `undefined`, the other will be `string`.

[Sample Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIBE4Fs4HMLoRhzAA2AzgEJzkoDeAsAFDKvLA76oAmAXMuTBRQuANzMAvs2ZgAngAcUGbHgJESFZAF5kACmZtkAH2R12fAUJGjkUCDGgQQSHvwCuIbvdARuyKSxsJmZ2DnbOEK6WwiBi5u6e3iC+-gZBprb2jhFRgjFxwBZ5Iv4AlMgAZGmsypxqxGRUNBDiTMwA9O3I+GBRutwq+IQNpPy1qsMa5OVaAHzRIswIAPYggt1EPNp6A3WTZGOYe+qNM-O7EyekAHSFyAD898gXQ1fXodku3NJMK2tgz2WAGVllgiAALEQAWWWdgA6sAwOD9podP1BvUNIcMSjptp5oxAqxgDAdji3nctFTkB4vDAfNxyoTDIYXpiyLc-J0aYl6clvkSWWyUe8suEvshucVYtV-MgIBQUCSyccRqKwk4JVSdLSkr4mbLWeS1XcpVYZYKjaqNOrPpEuV1dXzfLKJPLFRluatSLJkPJluRyMAAEakRG+kDLADu7HIABpkMHlkjkHA7M89QKWWxhRSHQsLdnWLm1R9xfbJV1pbhXbKSzaOKottyo7CANbkeUAN2gsij4MckiAA)

Comment: The problem is that I want the compiler to understand that one of the two (id, referenceId) will always be present. The getId function should always return a string, because the object will always have an id - either called id or referenceId.

Comment: @rahulthewall Given `IDamageDetails` in the answer, you can use a nullish coalescing operator for that purpopse (see updated answer).